# Making a snippet more efficient

Tags: jquery, performance

So... I have this code here that i`m using for a quiz and i was wondering if i can make it more efficient... mot of all I want the code to be shorter if possible. If you have some suggestion please tell me!

```
$("#done").click(function(){
            var c1 = 0,c2 = 0,c3 = 0;
            switch ($("input[name='question1']:checked").val()){
                case 1: c1++;
                break;
                case 2: c2++;
                break;
                case 3: c3++;
            }

            //repeats 6 times with the number of the question incremented every time
           switch ($("input[name='question8']:checked").val()){
                case 1: c1++;
                break;
                case 2: c2++;
                break;
                case 3: c3++;
            }

         });
```

Comment: So the only difference between your code snippets is the number after *question*. Try using a for loop and loop 8 times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always iterate all your questions with `$.each()` and your input names are selected based on ^(starts with word) question

```
$("#done").click(function(){
    var c1 = 0,c2 = 0,c3 = 0;
    $('input[name^=question]:checked').each(function(){
       switch(parseInt($(this).val())){
            case 1: c1++;break;
            case 2: c2++;break;
            case 3: c3++;break;
       }
    });
    console.log(c1 + " " + c2 + " " + c3);
});
```

**Edit 2** : Added a parseInt since our case varaiables are expecting numbers

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJXBWe - this should log every time it searches through questions at every question, but it does not work, can you tell me how to troubleshoot?

Comment: Can you also post the HTML in the pen

Comment: updated Pen [http://codepen.io/anon/pen/waLZmG](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/waLZmG)

Comment: we didn't have jquery check now